# Error EJB Timer Service is not available. Timers for application will not be deleted

Tags: java, servlets, timer, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I created Stateless bean, which has method with @Schedule annotation. I create instance of my bean in servlet. Code of bean:

```
 @Stateless
 public class StockServerBean {
 private String price=null;
 private ArrayList<String> nasdaqSymbols = new ArrayList<String>();
 private String chooseSymb;
 public String getChooseSymb() {
  return chooseSymb;
}

public void setChooseSymb(String chooseSymb) {
  this.chooseSymb = chooseSymb;
}

public StockServerBean(){
// Define some hard-coded NASDAQ symbols
nasdaqSymbols.add("AAPL");
nasdaqSymbols.add("MSFT");
nasdaqSymbols.add("YHOO");
nasdaqSymbols.add("AMZN");
nasdaqSymbols.add("MOT");
}

@Schedule(second="*",minute="*",hour="18,00-22,00", dayOfWeek="Mon-Sun")
public void getQuote(){
if(nasdaqSymbols.indexOf(chooseSymb.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
// Generate a random price for valid symbols
price = (new Double(Math.random()*100)).toString();
}
Session session = null;
Connection conn = null;
ConnectionFactory factory = null;
try{
    Context jndiC = new InitialContext();
    factory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiC.lookup("MyTestConnectionFactory");
    Queue queue = (Queue)jndiC.lookup("MyJMSTestQueue");

    conn = factory.createConnection();
    conn.start();

    session = conn.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(queue); 
    TextMessage outM = session.createTextMessage(chooseSymb + " : " + price);
    sender.send(outM);
    sender.close();
    System.out.println("Succesfully placed a price of  "  + chooseSymb + " :"+ price);

}catch(JMSException je){
    System.out.println("Error: " + je.getMessage());
}catch(NamingException ne){
    System.out.println("Error: " + ne.getMessage());
    ne.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        session.close();
        conn.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Can't close session/connection :" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

Code of my servlet:

```
  @WebServlet("/ExecutionServlet")
  public class ExecutionServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public ExecutionServlet() {
 super();
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 /**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse        response)
*/
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
StockServerBean bean = new StockServerBean();
bean.setChooseSymb("AAPL");
bean.getQuote();
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("Sending price to the queue");

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
 */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse       response) throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
doGet(request, response);
```

In result I obtain error:

> cannot Deploy Lesson32 deploy is failing=Error occurred during
>   deployment: Exception while loading the app: EJB Timer Service is not
>   available. Please see server.log for more details.

Code of error:

> [2015-10-29T21:53:23.581+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE]
>   [NCLS-CORE-00026]                [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)]    [timeMillis: 1446148403581] [levelValue: 1000] [[ Exception during lifecycle
>   processing java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Timer Service is not
>   available

I add property, as writed http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2434/ggrvi.html#glhnl and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. As your EJB seems to be correct and glassfish tries to start your timer method but throws a more general exception, I think, glassfish is not correctly configured.